# MongoDB replication as a service on windows

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to configure a replica set on windows as a service, means that even the PC will restart the mongod will run again automatically.
problem is that I run the mongod like this:

```
mongod --dbpath "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\data" --logpath "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\log\mongod.log" --port 27017 --storageEngine=wiredTiger --journal --replSet test_replica
```

And once I close the CMD running this command the service is killed. How do I run it correctly then?

Also, currenctly the service is navigating to the default cfg file but I see the replication there is marked with # (so the service is running as standalone). and when I try to add to replication the replSet: test_replica it won't start anymore.

Comment: You can start MongoDB standalone as a service, not a replica-set.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB as windows service and setting up replicaSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17413588/mongodb-as-windows-service-and-setting-up-replicaset)

Comment: You should upvote helpful answers and mark the best one as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put all your parameters into a [configuration file](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/index.html). Then you can create the service like this:

```
mongod.exe --config c:\MongoDB\config\mongod.cfg --install
```

For a replica set you typically create several services, not just one. It is possible to run a replica set with just one member, however this is quite useless. Of course, when you create several services then each one needs his own config file (and also his own dbPath, port, etc.)

The next time your PC will boot, the mongo service should also start. Or start it manually with command `net start <mongo service name>`

Comment: How do I configure the replication section on the cfg file on windows? just adding replSet: replication_name and then i can start it like you just mentioned? or there's additional i need to write ? like members or its something i can add also later?

Comment: Just the replSet name, And the service name must be different as well.

Comment: if i run the services on different machines, does the name matter?

Comment: No, of course then you can use the same config file everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should install mongodb as windows service. Read the [guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#follow-the-mongodb-edition-edition-installation-wizard) from the official documentation[image]
2. Setting `--replSet` from command line or `replication:replSetName` in configuration file is not enough. Read [this guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/), in short: after mongodb process is started in replica set mode, you should run `rs.initiate()` in mongo shell.

Comment: I did both, I know how to make it to start as replica set problem is now that the config file stay the same. replication is marked with # even when i start it with --replset and even when the replica set is already running and it has 3 instances in it. i followed this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438055/how-can-i-run-mongodb-as-a-windows-service in order to start the mongod as repl set and service but again the config file stay as default.

Comment: @pythonmaniac Config file and command line arguments are two different ways to run mongodb. If you want to provide all parameters manually - use command line arguments, if you want to use config file - you should do something like `mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf`. **Configuration file won't be modified automatically.** Uncomment and set replication section in config file and run mongod process with `config` parameter, if you want to do it through config file. But I see you already did all staff through command line. So you don't need config file at all.

Comment: Thanks for the help, didn't know that once I run all through cmd it won't take effect on the cfg file. in case I do want to modify the cfg file what the minimal things i need to do on the replication section? just replSet: replication_name? or I also need to mention the members here? and if i do modify it on the cfg file and also run all through the cmd (like i did) will it still work? (its like the cfg file is modifed but i don't use it but will it work and won't cause errors?