# My secondary nodes on my replica set close after I initiate the replica set

Tags: mongodb, windows

My project is an app for a service-based company, as well as a general-purpose full stack boilerplate/template. The app has been up and running for months in development. This issue occurred initially 2 days ago.

In order to start my replica set, I first open 6 separate command prompt windows as admin. I then set the dbpath etc. for the primary:

```
 mongod --dbpath "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\replicaComplex2\rep01\data" --logpath "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\replicaComplex1\rep01\log\mongod.log" --port 30000 --storageEngine=wiredTiger --journal --replSet jupiter_rep1
```

Then in a new terminal I set the config:

```
mongo --port 30000

rsconfig={_id:"jupiter_rep1",members:[{_id:0,host:"localhost:30000"}]}
```

I usually have to reconf in order to set the primary:

```
----reconf          
rsconf = rs.conf()          
rsconf.members = [{_id: 0, host: "localhost:30000"}]            
rs.reconfig(rsconf, {force: true})
```

I then initialize the replica set:

```
rs.initiate(rsconfig)
```

Then I go to a new terminal/prompt and set the dbpath for the other two nodes:

```
mongod --dbpath "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\replicaComplex2\rep02\data" --logpath "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\replicaComplex1\rep02\log\mongod.log" --port 30001 --storageEngine=wiredTiger --journal --replSet jupiter_rep1
```

And the same for the third node.

However, this is where I am running into the problem. At this point the secondary nodes close out before I can actually set them as secondary.

I first tried to close all the windows and restart the actual machine. Nope.

Second, I uninstalled mongo dB and reinstalled it. Nope.

Third, I started the two secondary nodes prior to the primary or initialization. When i start the primary and initialize the replica set the secondary nodes shut down.

I'm on windows...
I also have the MongoDB Server stopped.

Input is appreciated!

Update*
I didn't include the log file error in my original question. They are separated for easier reading.

> {"t":{"$date":"2022-04-15T16:05:44.353-05:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"ROLLBACK", "id":21606,   "ctx":"BackgroundSync","msg":"Finding
> common point"}

> {"t":{"$date":"2022-04-15T16:05:44.353-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",
> "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to
> refresh key
> cache","attr":{"error":"ReadConcernMajorityNotAvailableYet: Read
> concern majority reads are currently not
> possible.","nextWakeupMillis":800}}

> {"t":{"$date":"2022-04-15T16:05:44.377-05:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"ROLLBACK", "id":21607,   "ctx":"BackgroundSync","msg":"Rollback
> common
> point","attr":{"commonPointOpTime":{"ts":{"$timestamp":
> {"t":1649857370,"i":1}},"t":149}}}

> {"t":{"$date":"2022-04-15T16:05:44.378-05:00"},"s":"F",
> "c":"ROLLBACK", "id":51121,   "ctx":"BackgroundSync","msg":"Common
> point must be at least stable
> timestamp","attr":{"commonPoint":{"$timestamp":
> {"t":1649857370,"i":1}},"stableTimestamp":{"$timestamp":
> {"t":1649857964,"i":1}}}}

> {"t":{"$date":"2022-04-15T16:05:44.378-05:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",
> "id":23091,   "ctx":"BackgroundSync","msg":"Fatal
> assertion","attr":{"msgid":51121,"file":"src\mongo\db\repl\rollback_impl.cpp","line":1146}}

> {"t":{"$date":"2022-04-15T16:05:44.378-05:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",
> "id":23092,   "ctx":"BackgroundSync","msg":"\n\n***aborting after
> fassert() failure\n\n"}

Thanks!

Comment: Do you run all mongod's on the same machine?

Comment: Yes, in separate terminal windows

Comment: OK, why do you run replica set on a single machine?

Comment: Each node just needs its own port.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues in your setup, thus I put them all in an answer, although it would be rather a comment.

- Have a look at the logfiles `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\replicaComplex1\rep01\log\mongod.log` and `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\replicaComplex1\rep02\log\mongod.log`

  They should show you the error message, I don't see any reason why the processes should stop.
- Why do you have to have to reconf in order to set the primary? Does not make any sense. You should follow the [Deploy a Replica Set](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/) tutorial.
- I suggest to use a [configuration file](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/configuration-options/) instead of command line options. Pay attention to the [Windows Service Options](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/configuration-options/#windows-service-options)
- You should install MongoDB as a service, see [mongod.exe](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/program/mongod.exe/), for example `mongod --install --config C:\ProgramData\MongoDB\rep01\mongod.conf`. The the services will start automatically at boot time.
- Storage engine `wiredTiger` and enabled `journal` are default, you can skip these options.
- As the name implies `C:\Program Files\...` is typically not the place where you store application data and logfiles. Usually in `C:\Program Files\...` you find only the binaries. Consider a different location, e.g. `C:\ProgramData\MongoDB\...` of `C:\MongoDB\...`

Comment: Wow, nice. Ill fix it up and see you back here!

Answer (score 0):

At the suggestion of @Wernfried Domscheit,  I created a mongo replica set service and, in the process, I did find the issue.

To create the replica service, I used the following [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17413588/mongodb-as-windows-service-and-setting-up-replicaset).

Apparently, the log and dB path in my three config files all had the same link to the first node of the set. This is how it was months ago when I first copied and pasted the first config file to create the other two. So, I am thinking my external hard drive disconnected and some memory issue occurred. So due to the log paths being the same I got the log path error.

Thanks.

*Will switch to a Bluetooth set-up.